# How to use preg_match for extracting custom tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i use this pattern `'/(\{(\w+)\}(.*))?\{%(\w+)%\}((.*)\{\/(\w+)\})?/i'` to extract tags from a template using `preg_match` function.

**sample template:**

```
<table id="middle" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
    {middle}
    <tr>
        {left}<td>{%left%}</td>{/left}
        <td>{%middle%}{%content%}</td>
        {right}<td>{%right%}</td>{/right}
    </tr>
    {/middle}
</table>
```

how to make sure that `start` and `end` of each tag truly match it's name
in this example `middle` tag matches for both `middle` and `content` while it should just match `middle` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this problem would be do this in a few different steps.

First, you should use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with `/(?>{([^}]+)})(.*)?{\/\1}/sim` as your regular expression. This will find the top level {tag}{/tag}. The $matches[2] will contain the content (without the tags) while $matches[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) will contain the tag itself.

You should create a function that's called recursively so that in the callback, it's called again on $matches[2] so find the children {tags} just in case there are more. This is how you'll go through the tree.

Finally, you should make a third function that handles the {%tag%}. I would use preg_replace_callback again and make use of the switch statement to handle the tag name.

This should point you in the right direction.

**EDIT: Here is a fully functional demo of what I described above:**\

```
<?php

$content = <<<END
{a}
  {b}I like {%first%} {%last%} a {c}lot{/c}.{/b}
{/a}
END;

echo find_tags($content);

function find_tags($content)
{
  return preg_replace_callback('/(?>{([^}]+)})(.*)?{\/\1}/sim', 'find_tags_callback', $content);
}

function find_tags_callback($matches)
{
  // Find and process any children tag pairs.
  $matches[2] = find_tags($matches[2]);
  
  // Process the tags {%tag%}.
  $matches[2] = preg_replace_callback('/{%([^%]+)%}/sim', 'process_tags', $matches[2]);
  
  switch ( $matches[1] )
  {
    case 'a':
      $tag = 'div';
      
      break;
    case 'b':
      $tag = 'p';
      
      break;
    case 'c':
      $tag = 'b';
      
      break;
  }
  
  return '<'.$tag.'>'.$matches[2].'</'.$tag.'>';
}

function process_tags($matches)
{
  switch ( $matches[1] )
  {
    case 'first':
      return 'Francois';
      
      break;
    case 'last':
      return 'Deschenes';
      
      break;
  }
}

//
```

The resulting string will be: `<div><p>I like Francois Deschenes a <b>lot</b>.</p></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

1I'm confident, but not certain, that to make sure the enclosing tags({this}{/this}) match the data tags ({%this%}), you would need an accompanying if statement to test the returned strings.

I would use the preg_replace_callback function, like so:

```
<?php
$str = '<template contents>';
$newstr = preg_replace_callback(
'/(\{(\w+)\}(.*))?\{%(\w+)%\}((.*)\{\/(\w+)\})?/i', 
'check', //<-- the function to send matches to
$str);
function check($matches){
    if($matches[1] == $matches[2] && $matches[1] == $matches[3]){
        /*Do Work*/
        return ''; //new formatted string to send back to the $newstr var
    }
}
?>
```

the preg_replace_callback function sends any matches found as an array to the specified function for processing, then you return the new formatted string from that function.

Comment: you don't need an if statement. Doing it this way will actually result in many invalid matches, especially: {a}{b}{/b}{/a} will result in {a}{/b}. You need to look into [regular expression back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). See my example. This solution also won't work if the tags are on multiple lines.